# GCP Sftp: Lstat failing using Golang sftp client

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, sftp

I've got a program which connects to an SFTP server (hosted in Google Cloud), writes some files and then checks that the file was actually created. Something in the lines of:

```
outputPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", "myDir", "myFileName.txt")
// sftpClient is of type *sftp.Client
f, err := sftpClient.OpenFile(outputPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create file %s. Error: %s", outputPath, err)
}
defer f.Close()

// write the file
if _, err := f.Write(data); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("file %s created by write failed: %s", outputPath, err)
}

// verify if the file exist
_, err := sftpClient.Lstat(outputPath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("file %s was written by lstat failed: %s", outputPath, err)
}

...
```

the file is being written correctly, I can see it in the server in the specified location BUT when it reaches the `Lstat` command it is throwing an error:

> "file /myDir/myFileName.txt was written by Lstat failed: file does not exist"

I'm using the package `github.com/pkg/sftp`.

Any idea what's going on?

---

**Update**

As some of you mentioned I'm closing the file. Yet I'm still seeing the error.

```
outputPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", "myDir", "myFileName.txt")
// sftpClient is of type *sftp.Client
f, err := sftpClient.OpenFile(outputPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create file %s. Error: %s", outputPath, err)
}

// write the file
if _, err := f.Write(data); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("file %s created by write failed: %s", outputPath, err)
}

// closing the file after writing to it 
f.Close()

// verify if the file exist
_, err := sftpClient.Lstat(outputPath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("file %s was written by lstat failed: %s", outputPath, err)
}

...
```

Comment: You are creating the file with `O_WRONLY`, so you may not be able to stat it. You also haven't closed the file yet, so `Lstat` may not return the latest data.

Comment: if this is equivalent to https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat you shouldn't need read on the file, just the directories in path.  I think you should try closing the file before stat.  The writes are probably still pending

Comment: following both your suggestions now i'm closing the file after writing yet i'm seeing the same error. The question was updated to reflect the change

Comment: Check the error on `Close()`. You might have a delayed error. Also, as a test specify the full path to `myFileName.txt` instead of a local path.

Comment: You also didn't try `O_RDWR` (or `sftpClient.Create`, which does the same thing). It doesn't seem like it should make a difference, but lets rule out any extra variables.

Comment: Closing the file without deferring worked. Changes weren't pushed initially reason why I was seeing the same error. After confirming the changes were pushed I don't see the error anymore, thanks. This is kinda weird since the very same code was working fine in AWS (with `defer`) and once we moved to GCP it starting throwing the error